# Getting this error android studio 3.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

Program type already present:

```
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with build.gradle?